# Premoderation for webform submission before contact record change

Tags: webform-civicrm, workflow

We've a Webform which picks and updates existing contact's data. Is it possible to add a "check data" step somehow after webform submission has been made but before actual contact record change? There seems to be no corresponded event-condition-action chain in Rules/Webform Rules/CiviRules.

Comment: here is another dart in the dark (nice phrase). look at giving users only the option to create Draft webform submissions (maybe just hide 'submit' via js) - then you take over and do the actual Submission.

Comment: Pete I was just trying to think of something similar to this and you nailed it.  You should post this as an answer.

Comment: Perhaps amend to say that this only works for authenticated users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggest you look at giving users only the option to create Draft webform submissions (maybe just hide 'submit' via js) - then you take over and do the actual Submission

Answer (score 2):

Webform validation module can run a number of checks on specific fields on your webform - https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_validation

If you're worried about SPAM submissions install Mollom: https://www.drupal.org/project/mollom - and configure it to monitor your webform submissions.

Comment: Sounds great,thank you; we are more in need of "human validation" tool though.

Comment: As in, you're trying to make sure the webform submission was made by a human (and not a bot), or you need a human to check the data before Civi is updated?

Comment: Hey yurg - please be more/very specific as to what you meant when you wrote "check data" - or we're just throwing darts in the dark :-)

Comment: @Allen Hutchison The latter I guess: default data consistency checks are fine, it's more about content check group of "moderators" performs on "decent users" submission.

Comment: @ KarinG You're absolutely right, sorry; have just thought about this for a while, so it is clear for me only.. It's a content checks, hence, "human touch" is needed.

Comment: ah - if you're worried about spam - have you tried Mollom module? I'll amend my answer.

Comment: A lot of spam can be removed by setting a Validation rule that First name must not equal Last name ;-)